# React Native. How do I keep focus to a text input when the page re-renders on timer tick

Tags: android, react-native, android-textinputlayout, cljsrn

I'm writing a timer app using react native on android in clojurescript (using reagent hopefully not important).

I have a `TextInput` where I accept text from the user to name the timers.  Whenever my timer ticks, the entire android application re-renders and I lose focus on the `TextInput`.  I am currently using `onChangeText` to save the characters I am typing, is there a way to keep focus on the text input while the timer is ticking?.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `View.requestFocus();`? And I do not understand why "application re-renders" on each tick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to call `this.refs.yourTextInput.focus()` inside of the `componentDidUpdate` method. However, this will likely cause the keyboard to animate down, and then animate up again.

The root of the problem is that your timer value and your TextInput share the same scope, so when the state is updated, both the timer and TextInput are re-rendered via the `render` function. Ideally, you can:

Put your timer text in a custom component, and add a method on that custom component to set its own state. This will cause only the custom component to re-render as long as the custom component's state is the one which is updating.

Comment: This may work (and I'm probably going to accept it for bounty) but it does require some stateful changes without a single state tree so it's not purely functional.  I'm sort of wondering if there is a solution that adheres to https://github.com/staltz/flux-challenge.  I'm hypothesizing react + flux like architectures have problems with user input + asynchronous updates.